# Stop powerline hovering above bottom of full-screen terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

When in full-screen mode ("full-full", not just maximised with menu bar still showing) Powerline inside Terminal.app hovers slightly (about it's own height) above the bottom of the screen.

Does anyone know of a fix, resting it on the bottom 'as normal'?

I'm using a 2013 MBA (in case affected by resolution). If I resize it while not full-screened, it resides on the bottom at all heights. So this is certainly a bug; not due to number of rows available.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot and explain one on earth Powerline  is?

Comment: @unknowndomain If you don't know what jy is, I doubt very much you'll be able to answer.. I initially hoped for a config option, but now I suspect it may just be a bug. As for what it is, feel free to utilise Google.

Comment: Ollie, I am trying to help here, I use terminal all the time and have no idea what Powerline is, I doubt many others do, I did search Google but nothing much came up and I was hoping that rather than a flippant response you might actually just explain a little and I could perhaps help.

Comment: @unknowndomain It's a configurable status line for vim/tmux/shell. The issue and therefore question is, I suspect, pretty specific to powerline which is why I was flippant in thinking you probably can't answer. I'm asking on Apple.SE (as opposed to say Unix) because it's only an issue in Terminal.app and when full-screened, which makes it also quite Apple-specific.

Comment: Did you try Command + K

Comment: Nope, didn't know that one, but no change.

Comment: Command + then Command -... Trying to find a way for the terminal to redraw.

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't just in Powerline, it is the default behaviour when you move a Terminal window from windowed mode to fullscreen mode. This can be verified with:

`nano`

You'll see that in this text editor there is additional space at the bottom of the screen when in fullscreen mode that isn't there during windowed mode.

I suspect this is because it would be undesirable to have the text hard to the edge of the screen.

My cursory glance round the internet didn't find anyone else reporting this issue, so I suspect it's not come up that much, there doesn't appear to be a way around this.

Comment: Damn. You're right, nice spot, thanks. I never noticed this before, but I guess it's not noticeable (and actually looks better as you say) generally, but when you have a solid colour intended to run along the bottom it's a little jarring.. Hopefully the devs will come up with something.

Comment: I imagine Apple's put some padding on there, why don't you try another Terminal emulator like XTerm.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid it, but yeah I will if not luck any other way, thanks.